# Arrange picker to be in center of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipicker

I have an `UITableView` to which has a cell to which I add a custom picker (`[[cell contentView] addSubview:picker]`) with a custom size `CGRectMake(0,0,320,180)`. On an iphone screen everything looks fine but on an ipad the picker is on the left side of the screen. How do I arrange the picker/subview in the cell so its in the center and not on the left side?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or nib? Or are you crafting it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIPickerView` will center in its own size. So if you manage to make it resizing with the cell, it should be good.

Problem here is that you define a fixed width for your picker view. If you want it to work , you need to set the good width in each situation.

You can manage to do it by :

1. looking about the device (so you set the width of the screen) ; *It's the easy but dirty solution*
2. set a resizing mask to your `UIPickerView` so it resize with the cell ; *It's a hard solution, but correct*
3. use AutoLayout so your `UIPickerView` will be constraint to the cell width ; *It's the nice solution, but restricted to iOS6 and more*